# cmake: add defines of data types handled as string

Tags: cmake

Standard C
I need to add data  types to project because GNU do not understand some C51 data types. Example need a BYTE types as:

```
#define BYTE unsigned char
```

Have tried following examples:

```
add_definitions(-DBYTE=\"unsigned char\")
add_definitions(-DBYTE="unsigned short")
add_definitions(-DBYTE="\"unsigned long\"")
```

Some other ideas?

thanks :-)

Comment: what is your exact problem? does the `add_definition` work for you? if not, which errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
add_definitions("-DBYTE=unsigned char")
```

Answer (score -1):

Antonio's suggestion is pretty good. But in case you are looking for using the defines at configure time, you can use the approach mentioned in your question.

To add more information, you can use something like:

```
set(MYDEFINES -DVAR1=value1 -DVAR2=value2)
add_definitions(${MYDEFINES})
```

add_definitions() accepts a list which is very useful sometimes. You don't have to convert to a string.

Comment: The question asked was how to handle values with spaces in them, this answer does not address this.